# Finding overlapping coordinates of two anchors and capturing overlapping image coordinates in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, opencv, swiftui

I'm working on an iOS project using Swift, and I'm trying to identify overlapping coordinates between two anchors in a 2D space. Additionally, I want to capture the corresponding coordinates in an image. I'm encountering challenges with the implementation and would appreciate guidance or Swift code examples.

I have two anchors in a 2D space, represented by CGRects or CGPoint pairs:

```
let anchorA: CGRect = CGRect(x: x1, y: y1, width: width1, height: height1)
let anchorB: CGRect = CGRect(x: x2, y: y2, width: width2, height: height2)
```

I need to determine the overlapping region between `anchorA` and `anchorB`. Once the overlapping coordinates are identified, I want to map these coordinates to an image captured by the device.

If anyone has experience with a similar task or could provide Swift code snippets for calculating overlapping coordinates and mapping them to image coordinates, that would be immensely helpful.

Comment: [`intersection`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1455346-cgrectintersection)?